# Environment variables don't work in Liquidsoap

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-22.04, liquidsoap

I've spent all night trying to get environment variables to take their value in Liquidsoap.

The result they return is always empty.

```
log("Variable SOURCE_PASSW: " ^ getenv("SOURCE_PASSW"))
log("Variable PASSWORD_DJ: " ^ getenv("PASSWORD_DJ"))
log("Variable PASSWORD_ADMIN: " ^ getenv("PASSWORD_ADMIN"))

2023/08/22 09:40:25 [lang:3] Variable SOURCE_PASSW: 
2023/08/22 09:40:25 [lang:3] Variable PASSWORD_DJ: 
2023/08/22 09:40:25 [lang:3] Variable PASSWORD_ADMIN:
```

I have defined the environment variables here:
`/etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
TELNET_USERNAME=client_metadata
TELNET_PASSWORD=985421
ADMIN_ICECAST=admin
PASSWORD_ADMIN=9632541
PASSWORD_DJ=20548798
SOURCE_PASSW=05897445
RELAY_PASSW=635478
```

In Ubuntu 22.04 SSH console they work fine:

```
icecast2@ip-17x-xx-xx-xxx:~/liquidsoap-daemon/script$ echo $PASSWORD_ADMIN

9632541
```

Icecast version: Icecast 2.4.4

Liquidsoap version: Liquidsoap 2.1.4 (installed with OCaml Package Manager (opam))

Does anyone know a way to make them work for me in the .liq script?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution.
I forgot to mention that I use liquidsoap as a daemon.
I edited the service file and added the line

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

And that did the magic!:)